# how to modify items in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a list such as this

```
L = ['a','b','c','d',]
```

How do I modify items to e.g. caps as this or **BOLD**:

```
L =['A','B','C','D',]
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: So what have you tried? If it's all letters, you can add to the ASCII code or make them all uppercase using `string.upper()`

Comment: sorry i overlooked inserting what I have tried. Thanks @Oisin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upper()` is a string method, but strings are iterables and can be converted to and from strings, so in addition to the solution already proposed you can do:

```
list(''.join(L).upper())
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a generator/list comprehension:

```
L = ['A','B','C','D',]
output = [i.upper() for i in L]
```

Ths will excecute the upper method on all elements in the list L.

Comment: This is really a list comprehension.